# Creating a sequence in python 3

Tags: python

```
a=1
b=1
sum=(a+b)
for i in range(100):
print(a)
print(b)
 print(sum)
```

This is my current code, but I don't know how to create a code to do continuous addition to produce a sequence in python with basic math computation. I need a+b to equal c and b+c=d and so on but I don't know how to formulate that into code.

The question: Starting with two one-digit positive integers a and b, consider the sequence in which the next number is the digit in the ones place of the sum of the previous two numbers. And that returns the length of the sequence when the last two numbers repeat the values of a and b for the first time. For example, if a = 1 and b = 1, the function should return 62.

The output of this sequence should be 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 4, 3, 7, 0, ... when a=1 and b=1. Overall, I just need major help and it would be greatly appreciated if I could get my code edited and revised to produced the output.

I tried simple math computations in python.

No, there's no error messages but I need help to get to desired output.

Comment: The main portion of your question is called a fibonacci sequence and you can find code all over the internet and this site for how to solve it in Python. You'll then need to make the necessary adjustments for your homework problem since they made some changes so that you couldn't just use internet answers for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this. Hope this logic might help you.

```
a=1
b=1

print("%d","%d",a,b)
for i in range(5):
 c=a+b
 print(c)
 a=b
 b=c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break this problem into two problems. The first one is to compute the sequence. The second is to use the solution of the fist one to find when the sequence starts to repeat.

The first one can be solved with a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Basically, it is a function that behaves like an iterator.

```py
def gen():
    a=1
    b=1
    yield a
    yield b
    while True:
        result = (a + b) % 10
        a = b
        b = result
        yield result
```

You can print the generated values with

```py
for value in gen():
    print(value)
```

But it will be too fast to see. Instead we can do something such as

```py
g = gen()
print(g.__next__())
print(g.__next__())
print(g.__next__())
print(g.__next__())
# etc etc
```

It prints the sequence correctly. Now we need to find the period of the sequence. We can create another function for that.

```py
def findPeriod():
    period = 0
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for value in gen():
        b = a
        a = value
        period += 1
        if a == 1 and b == 1 and period > 2:
            return period
```

Notice that we know that the sequence will repeat again when both `a` and `b` are equal to `1`. When that happens the function will return the period (excluding the first time).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input("Enter a :"))
b = int(input("Enter b:"))

m = a
n = b

sum = a+b
a = b
b = sum
count = 0

while a != m or b!=n:
    print("inside while")
    count +=1
    print(count)
    sum = a+b
    if sum<100:
        value = sum % 10
    else:
        value = sum % 100
    a = b
    b = value


print("The length is :")
print(count+3)
```

From your queries i understand that its not a Fibonacci Series that you want to create, instead you want a different one. I hope the above code helps you to solve your problem.